# Multiply in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Multiply the data in one column and create a new column with the answer?

I would just like the function needed. I have tried `Select col1 From table where col1*.1 As new col.`

for ind, row in amount.interrows():
    amount.loc[ind, "discountPrice"] = row['amount']*.1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select col1, col1 * 0.1 new_col1 from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you I was making this much harder than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for faster computations

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("db_name")

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from my_table;", conn)
```

then you can do any operation with ease

For egs

```
df['multilpy_col'] = df['col']*0.1
```